# Como hago para sumar los string que están dentro de estos array ["1","4"] ["1","0"]

Tags: javascript, html, array, function, javascript-metodo

Estoy haciendo un ciclo que recorre los numeros pares de una tarjeta y los numeros >=10 deben ser sumados entre si, ya logre obtener cuales son los valores >=10 pero ahora no se como sumarlos entre si, ayuda por favor. alli muestro mi funcion.

```
const validator = {
    isValid: function (creditCardNumber){
        let numberPosition = creditCardNumber.split("").reverse(); //Ingreso el numero de tarjeta en un array, lo reversa y lo separa en string
        let sum = 0;

        //i inicia en 0 y siempre que i sea menor que arrayInverted.length continua el bucle incrementado en 1
        for(let i=0; i<numberPosition.length; i++){

            if (i%2 !=0){    //(%operador modulo: residuo) Si i residuo de dos es diferente a cero entonces la posicion es impar
                let newResult = (numberPosition[i]*2); // el resultado de las posiciones impares sera igual a mi arrayInverted de mi posicion i multiplicada por 2
                
                if(newResult >= 10){ //Si mi resultado de las posiciones impares es mayor o igual a 10 
                    let digitsPosition = newResult.toString().split(""); //el resultado de las posiciones impares metelas es un nuevo array y separalo en string
                    let sumNumber = 0;

                    console.log(digitsPosition);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

export default validator;
```

Comment: ¿Sumarlos como string "1" + "1" = "11" o sumarlos como números 1 + 1 = 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes una colección de arreglos pequeños en un arreglo grande  puedes recorrer cada arreglo pequeño con un `map`, y encontrar la suma de cada uno usando un `reduce`:

```js
const arreglo = [["1","4"],["1","0"]]

const sumas = arreglo.map(arr => {
  return arr.reduce((a,e) => Number(e) + a,0)
 })

console.log(sumas)
```

Suponiendo que quieras la suma neta de todo el arreglo conformado por subarreglos:

```js
const arreglo = [["1","4"],["1","0"]]
const suma =arreglo.flat().reduce((a,e) => Number(e) + a,0)

console.log(suma)
```

Suponiendo que tu arreglo no tiene subarreglos:

```js
const arreglo = ["1","4","1","0"]
const suma =arreglo.reduce((a,e) => Number(e) + a,0)

console.log(suma)
```

Comment: gracias me ayudo muchisimooo!!!

Answer (score 4):

Necesitas primero hacer el parse de String a Number, eso lo haces con un [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
Luego aplicas un [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para sumar todo.

```js
const arr = [ "1", "4", "7", "10" ];

const sum = arr.map(  n => Number( n ) )
.reduce( (curr, accum) => curr + accum, 0);

console.log( sum );
```

Comment: gracias gracias aprendi algo nuevo!